# Dual boot windows10 and Ubuntu-how to begin?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, installation, virtual-machine

I just installed VMWare workstation, what is first step for installation dual boot on my VM?

Comment: Hi Darko. System administrators on [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com) and advanced computer users on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com) might be even more knowledgeable on these topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just install windows and then after, install a an easy Linux, like Ubuntu.

The order is important, the fact the Ubuntu is friendly is important too.

When installing Windows leave empty space on your disk. When installing Ubuntu tell it to install itself along side Windows.

Comment: I have a task: 
Install win10 on partition with space 21.38GB and 
Ubuntu on two partition (total space 14.98GB)
 first with file-system ext4(mount point '/') and second partition ext3(mount point '/boot')? 
Do I need alocate total space 21.38+14.98 when I install windows or later for Ubuntu?

Comment: When you are installing Windows, use the custom installation as need to make sure you create one partition for windows, and leave the rest of the space empty 
In this case you will create a virtual machine with a disk with  21.38+14.98 GB and then install windows, first be creating a 21.38 partition on the virtual disk and install windows to that. Then boot the vm from a linux iso and ask it to install it along with windows.